# VisualStateManager for WPF and Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, shared-libraries

When you do code like

VisualStates.GoToState(this, useTransitions, VisualStates.StateNormal);

I believe this code will only work for  Silverlight apps.

will this affect the way a WPF app works...

Trying to incorportae controls that can be shared between both silverlight and WPF apps and was just wondering what were the main pitfalls were...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF Toolkit has added a "Visual State Manager" concept to WPF.  You can get it [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535), and read more about it [here](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-visual-state-manager-overview.aspx).